# Finding MEMS Accelerometer Nonlinearity Coefficient from %FSR Specification

Tags: mechanisms

I want to predict the maximum output error from nonlinearity for the working range of a MEMS accelerometer. I am given in the accelerometer spec sheet a nonlinearity value of 1% FSR for a ±40 g range. How do I convert the %FSR value to mg/g^2?

Taking the spec sheet error of 1% (0.01) and multiplying it by a 40 g yields a 0.400 g (400 mg) of error from nonlinearity at a 40 g input. Since the nonlinearity is a second-order error, the max error curve can be fitted to the 0.400 g value at 40 g. Thus the coefficient of nonlinearity would be 400 mg/40g^2 or 0.25 mg/g^2 which can be multiplied against each input value of interest under 40 g to get the rest of the nonlinearity error curve values. Is this correct?

Comment: IMHO, if you are after the maximum output error from nonlinearity then you should take the full range value i.e. 0.4g.

Comment: full scale span is 80g, not 40g ... so I read the "1% nonlinearity", as a *deviation from best fit straight line*, of up to 0.8g from the line. Without knowing about the fundamentals of the sensor technology, there's nothing to say the worst case non linearity wouldn't be at mid-span, i.e. at 0g  (although the offset associated with it would presumably be calibrated away).